# AttributeError: Tkinter Button instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code in question:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class Application(Frame):
    """Jungle Timers"""

    def __init__(self, master):
        """Initialize the Frame."""
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Buttons for timer."""
        #create buttons
        self.b1 = Button(self, text = "Own Blue Up In: 0", command = self.b1)
        self.b1.grid()

        self.r1 = Button(self, text = "Own Red Up In: 0", command = self.r1)
        self.r1.grid()

        self.b2 = Button(self, text = "Their Blue Up In: 0", command = self.b2)
        self.b2.grid()

        self.r2 = Button(self, text = "Their Red Up In: 0", command = self.r2)
        self.r2.grid()

        self.d = Button(self, text = "Dragon Up In: 0", command = self.d)
        self.d.grid()

        self.baron = Button(self, text = "Baron Up In: 0", command = self.baron)
        self.baron.grid()

    def b1(self):
        x = 300
        while x > 0:
            self.b1(text = "Own Blue Up In: " + str(x))
            x -= 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def r1(self):
        x = 300
        while x > 0:
            self.r1(text = "Own Red Up In: " + str(x))
            x -= 1
            time.sleep(1)   

    def b2(self):
        x = 300
        while x > 0:
            self.b2(text = "Their Blue Up In: " + str(x))
            x -= 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def r2(self):
        x = 300
        while x > 0:
            self.r2(text = "Their Red Up In: " + str(x))
            x -= 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def d(self):
        x = 360
        while x > 0:
            self.d(text = "Dragon Up In: " + str(x))
            x -= 1
            time.sleep(1)

    def baron(self):
        x = 420
        while x > 0:
            self.baron(text = "Baron Up In: " + str(x))
            x -= 1
            time.sleep(1)   

root = Tk()
root.title("Jungle Timers")
root.geometry("200x210")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

With this code I'm getting AttributeError: Button instance has no **call** method on line 37.

```
self.b1(text = "Own Blue Up In: " + str(x))
```

Am I doing this completely wrong or is there an easy way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
self.b1.config(text = "Own Blue Up In: " + str(x))
```